# DML operation INSERT not allowed on CaseShare when deploying from Developer Sandbox to Developer Pro

Tags: apex-sharing

I have this case trigger handler, works fine in sandbox:

```
CaseShare[] casesShar = new CaseShare[]{};
       for (case c: cs){
            if(c.OwnerId!=null && 
              oldCaseMap.get(c.Id).OwnerId != c.OwnerId && 
              (c.Status != 'Completed') &&
              c.ownerId!=usrMap.get(c.MyUser__c)){
                 casesShar.add(shareCasMethod(c.id, usrMap.get(c.MyUser__c), 'Edit')); }}
       Database.SaveResult[] sr = Database.insert(casesShar);

public static CaseShare casesShar(Id rId, Id uid, string lvl){
        CaseShare jobShr  = new CaseShare();
        jobShr.caseId = rId;
        jobShr.UserOrGroupId = uid;
        jobShr.CaseAccessLevel = lvl;
        jobShr.RowCause = 'Manual';
        return jobShr;
    }
```

Test method runs as system administrator profile, I can post it, but it is very basic.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out Case sharing wasn't enabled.

To do that, you will need to change organisation wide defaults (Security Controls>Sharing Settings), Case object 'Default External Access' to Private.